# How do you activate checkmarks in list activity?

Tags: android, listactivity, android-arrayadapter, checkmark

I have a ListActivity with an array adapter declared like `arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked);` This shows a bunch of rows with checkmarks on the far right. Can you tell me how to get a reference to those checkmarks or how to check/uncheck them?

Answer (score 8):

The CheckedTextView itself handles the checkbox. It is passed in as the second argument (View v) in the onListItemClick handler. So, you can simplify your code as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick( ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
  CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)v;
  textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked());
}
```

Comment: Note that it probably makes more sense to use `l.setItemChecked(position, !l.isItemChecked(position));` if your list views extend `Checkable`! (Which they do for android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked.) If you only check the `CheckedTextView`, it won't update the underlying data, e.g. isItemChecked() won't change.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and tried the solutions provided here but I still had a lot of problems.
I just wanted to have a list with selectable "test cases" and two buttons "select all tests" and "run selected tests" (therefore I didn't want to have just a ListActivity).
As mentioned by "JDC" **getChildAt** (and getChildCount) refer to the **currently displayed** items but my list didn't fit on the screen and therefore I couldn't use it to select **all** list items.
Additionally if I used **setChecked** of the **CheckedTextView** I had the problem that the selection disappeared as soon as I scrolled the list.
My solution is the code below that fixes these issues by using **getCount** and **setItemChecked** of the **ListView** (see also the comments in the source code). Additionally it shows how to retrieve the checked items.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    static final String[] names = new String[] { "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5", "Test 6", "Test 7", "Test 8", "Test 9", "Test 10"};
    ListView list;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above
        // appear in the ListView
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listOfTests);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, names));
    }

// This does not work.
// 1st: it checks only the displayed items
// 2nd: as soon as you scroll the list the selections are undone
//
//    public void onRunAllTestsClick (View view) {
//      int count = list.getChildCount();
//      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
//          ((CheckedTextView)list.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(true);
//    }

    // This is the solution
    // 1st: getCount deliveres the count of all list items (even if they are not displayed)
    // 2nd: calling setItemChecked on the ListView ensures that the ListView "knows" that the item is checked and does not destroy it if you scroll the list
    public void onRunAllTestsClick (View view) {
        int count = list.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            list.setItemChecked(i, true);
    }

    public void onRunSelectedTestsClick (View view) {
        SparseBooleanArray resultArray = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int size = resultArray.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (resultArray.valueAt(i))
                Log.i("CodecTestActivity", list.getAdapter().getItem(resultArray.keyAt(i)).toString());
    }
}
```

Here is also the appropriate layout (main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="onRunSelectedTestsClick" android:id="@+id/RunSelectedTestsClick" android:text="@string/runselectedtests"></Button>
        <Button android:text="@string/runalltests" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="onRunAllTestsClick" android:id="@+id/RunAllTests"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/listOfTests" android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can do is change the checkmark after a cell is clicked using:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick( ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
  CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)l.getChildAt(position);
  text.setChecked(!textView.isChecked());

  super.onListItemClick (l, v, position, id);
}
```

I would still like to be able to set the checkmarks without the user touching any cells.